# Enable semantic comletion TabNine in Sublime Text(Entering a command in Sublime Text)

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

As described in [This Guide](https://www.tabnine.com/semantic) , semantic completion is to be enabled by entering ´TabNine::sem´ into the Text Editor. I restarted Sublime Text and entered this in the Comand Palette; yet no reaction.

When using Sublime- Text, TabNine reminds the user to activate this to enable the python specific autocompletion.

Where to enter this Line : ´TabNine::sem´  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter it in the document itself. The TabNine::* commands are "magic strings" that TabNine picks from the document as you type.

Comment: totally forgot, your answer was correct and helpfull; best regards